# SVG path returns null and no event listener possible

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I add SVG to my HTML file as object

```
<object onclick='showStreet()' id="svg-object" data="svg/hamburg.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="width: 300px"></object>
```

Inside of the SVG itself there are paths, which I want to append a listener to. For Example:
`<path id="eimbuetel" class="cls-3" d="M203.4,135.53H191.48L182,132.62s-3.05-.39-4,0-5.5-3.07-6.42-3.07h-9.17l-3.66-2.2-10.39,2.2s-2.14,6-1.84,8.18,2.45,5,1.84,6.61-5.5,3.15-5.81,4.72a11.44,11.44,0,0,0,0,3.46l-4.28,6.3-9.47,9.44,6.72,5.9-15.28,11.72,24.14,22.35s3.06,12.9,4,12.9,6.11-5.67,6.11-5.67,4.58,2.21,4.58,3.15,1.23,9.76,1.23,9.76,8.55,12,10.69,12,9.48-1.26,10.09,0,11.61,10.83,11.61,10.83l5.81-5.17,2.44,5.17H211L223,258.89s12.53-7.73,11-7.73-14.37-30.35-14.37-30.35l-6.11.32-7.9,6.07-9.21-13,7.33-6.3s1.22-7.24-.3-6.61-5.51-8.18-5.51-8.18l1.53-13.53s-6.4,1.31-6.42-1.26,13.15-14.16,13.15-14.16l5.8-16.68-5.19-11Z" transform="translate(-13.31 -9.96)"/>`

```
document.getElementById('eimbuetel')
```

returns null

```
document.querySelectorAll('eimbuetel').length
```

returns 0

What's the issue?

Comment: you're using an object tag so its contents are a separate document. you'd need to get the object tag's document via var doc = document.getElementById("svg-object").contentDocument; and then call doc.getElementById('eimbuetel')

Comment: doc = document.getElementById("svg-object").contentDocument also returns null

Comment: did you run it after the object tag's onload event has fired?

Comment: window.onload = function () {
  var doc = document.getElementById("svg-object").contentDocument 
        console.log(doc); 
    } also returns null

Comment: window onload is not the same as the object tag's onload. I assume document.getElementById("svg-object") != null if it isn't then I imagine the file svg/hamburg.svg is likely invalid somehow.